# Can a C++ template parameter be empty?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
template <typename T>
struct thingo {
  int always;
  T sometimes;
};

thingo <> compile_error; // <- wont compile

thingo <nullptr_t> wastes_space; // compiles but nullptr_t takes space anyway
```

Is inheriting from an int wrapper the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure how an int wrapper would help this.

Comment: The syntax you use is used for something else:  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/, go down to "template specialization."

Comment: ...but as for what you're trying to do:  what _are_ you trying to do with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about:

```
struct None {};

// Or without an extra struct:
// typedef void None;

template <typename T = None>
struct thingo {
  int always;
  T sometimes;
};

template <>
struct thingo<None> {
  int always;
};
```

Comment: Sure - void is nice, too

Comment: `None` still has non-zero size.  You can inherit from it, however, in order for the empty base class optimization to take effect.